# Windows 7 outlook vertical emails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When emails are stacked vertically in the taskbar. How can you scroll over the emails in the taskbar with your mouse to view them so I don't have to click to open email in Outlook?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Do you have these emails open in Outlook already or what? And how do you want to be able to "scroll" over these emails?

Comment: Yes I have several emails open in outlook and they are vertically stacked not horizontal before I use to be able to show all open emails vertically stacked in the taskbar and when I would put my cursor over the stacked emails it would pop up a preview of the email. Now I have to click the email to open and view it the scroll over the email and view them as I would scroll over them was so convenient please help??

Answer (score 0):

No way, sorry. You must click on the window preview in taskbar to activate it and be able to interact with it (like scrolling with a mouse).